# Count argument in get_terms has no effect on ouput/doesn't work

Tags: taxonomy, terms, categories

I'm trying to get a count of the categories that are subcategories of a category with the id `$categoryId`.

In [the documentation for the term query object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/), which is the primary argument to get_terms, the `count` parameter is listed, with the description:

> (bool) Whether to return a term count (true) or array of term objects (false). Will take precedence over $fields if true. Default false.

Based off of this, I think the following code should return an integer term count. However, it does not, it returns an array of term objects, the same as if I didn't include the `count` argument. I've tried this with the values 1, "true", "True" and True as well.

```
get_terms(
    array(
        'parent' => $categoryId,
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'count' => true
    )
);
```

After searching more, I found this code, which works:

```
wp_count_terms( 'category', array( 'parent' => $categoryId ) );
```

Why does the `count` argument have no effect in this situation? Is this behavior consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from which version, but **count** argument not used anymore.
Just checked WP_Term_Query class and found nothing related to **count** argument in get_terms() method, but you can still find it in constructor of this class.
To return terms count only, you need to set **count** for **fields** argument.

```
get_terms(
    array(
        'parent' => $categoryId,
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'fields' => 'count'
    )
);
```

The function **wp_count_terms()** just do the same.

```
function wp_count_terms( $taxonomy, $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array('hide_empty' => false);
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

    if ( isset($args['ignore_empty']) ) {
        $args['hide_empty'] = $args['ignore_empty'];
        unset($args['ignore_empty']);
    }

    //HERE IT SETS COUNT VALUE FOR YOU
    $args['fields'] = 'count';

    return get_terms($taxonomy, $args);
}
```

It's not the first time I noticed, that english version of codex is outdated. For example spanish codex don't have a 'count' argument - https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Function_Reference/get_terms